# Global functional component hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm trying to apply conditional rendering of EVERY component. The idea is that this hook checks for specific property name passed to component and if this property is present and has a value, it must pass certain conditions to be rendered, if property is missing it is rendered as usual. So internal components of libraries wouldn't be hit by this hook because they are missing that property. I know that I can encapsulate every component to wrapper containing this logic, but it means complete rewriting and alot of extra code.

Purpose: rendering components based on user rights.

Example of what I would like to accomplish with use of undocumented(fictitious) code.

```
const useBeforeComponentRender = (props, next) => {
  // next() is functional Component
  const { userRightsArray } = AppContext;
  const requiredRights = props.renderWithRights;

  if (Array.isArray(requiredRights)) {
    if (requiredRights.some(r => userRightsArray.includes(r))) {
      return next();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return next();
}
React.hook({useBeforeComponentRender});

function ActionBox() {
  return (
    <EditButton renderWithRights=['edit', 'superAdmin']>
  )
}
```

Any advice(even different approach) will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. There's no middleware like in Express that would run for every component. Let's assume this would be possible, and imagine you use Typescript, how are you going to tell TS that every component accepts this extra prop (that they don't even use)? HOC is the way to go I'm afraid.

Comment: Adding an extra withRights() HOC around every component that must have this condition won't be too much of a hassle in my opinion.

Comment: @jperl I prefer straightfoward solutions so it was worth asking. Thanks